# norm in separable Hilbert space as countable supremum

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $H$ is an Hilbert space with inner product denoted by $(\cdot , \cdot )$, then
$$||u||=\sup \{(u,v):\:||v|| \leq 1 \}$$

**Question:** In the case that $H$ is separable, is there any countable family $\{ w_n\} \subset H$ such that $||u||=\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \, (u,w_n)$ ?

I know that in this case $H$ admists an orthonormal basis and the Parseval identity holds, but I don't know how to use it

Comment: How about all possible finite rational linear combinations of some countable orthonormal set? Would that work? I mean, consider a countable orthonormal basis $u_n$ on $H$, and consider the set $\{x :  x = \sum x_nu_n, |x_n|^2 \leq 1, x_n \in \mathbb Q \forall n\} = S$. Try to see if this works i.e. check if $||u|| = \sup_{s \in S} \langle u,s\rangle$

Comment: Just take a countable dense subset of the unit ball?

Answer (score 0):

The hints received in comments were useful (thank you)

The separable Hilbert space $H$ admits a countable orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$ and a dense subspace is given by the set $E$ of finite linear combinations with rational coefficients of the element of the basis. Denote by $ E_1=\{w_k:k \in \mathbb N\}$ the set of elements of $E$ with norm at most $1$.

Fix $u \in H$. I want to prove that

$$\sup\{(u,v):\,v \in H, ||v||\leq 1 \}=\sup_{k \in \mathbb N}\,(u,w_k)$$

and since one inequality is trivial I only need to prove this "$\le$"

For any $v \in H$ there exists a sequence $(v_n)$ in $E$ such that $v_n \to v$ in $H$. If $||v|| \leq 1$, then $v_n \in E_1$ for $n >>1$. Given $\epsilon >0$ arbitrary, choose $m >>1$ such that $||v-v_m||\leq \epsilon/||u||$. One has

$$(u,v_m)=(u,v)-(u,v-v_m)\geq (u,v)-\epsilon$$

thus $\sup_{k \in \mathbb N}\,(u,w_k) \geq (u,v)- \epsilon$. Taking the supremum over $v \in H$ with $||v||\leq 1$ and letting $ \epsilon \to 0^+$, the claim follows.